# Runtime error while obtaining PE headers from an application at runtime

Tags: c++, process, executable, portable-executable, inject

I have been trying to make a executable injector into process for WINDOWS, the program compiles without any errors, but when I run the program (via Microsoft Visual Studio's Debug mode) I get a runtime error. Visual studio highlights a line (i have marked it with comments)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

int main()
{
 PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
 PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS INTH;
 PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ISH;

 //Lets load the resource
 HRSRC hResource=FindResourceA(NULL,(LPCSTR)MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_EXE1),"EXE");
 DWORD ResourceSize=SizeofResource(NULL,hResource);
 HGLOBAL hGlob=LoadResource(NULL,hResource);
 LPSTR lpFileMaped=(LPSTR)LockResource(hGlob);

 //obtain the DOS and PE headers
 IDH=(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)&lpFileMaped[0];
 INTH=(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)&lpFileMaped[IDH->e_lfanew]; //this is the highlighted line
                                       // which supposedly causes an error at runtime

 ....
```

Why is that so, Could anyone elaborate?

Comment: The complete absence of any error checking will ultimately make the code bomb on an AccessViolation when you deference 0xcccccccc

Comment: +1 to the above comment -- are you sure the initial `FindResource` call is succeeding?  It's *always* better to check the return value of functions that may fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [standard work of Matt Pietrek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx).

> The e_lfanew field contains the file offset of the PE header